# Saving (Updating) Post / Page Edits With AJAX

Tags: ajax, tinymce, save-post

One of the major frustrations while editing posts/pages is that after saving, two things happen:

- The admin page is reloaded, which takes time
- More importantly, the cursor position is lost

If you're working on longer posts — especially when copy-editing, or if working in HTML mode and making small adjustments where frequent previews are needed — losing the current position, then finding the point where you left off is unnecessarily frustrating and time-consuming.

An elegant solution to this problem would be if the updates would be done over AJAX. Actually there used to be [a plugin for this](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ajax-save-post/), but it hasn't been updated in over 5 years and it doesn't work with current WP versions anymore.

Is there an (easy) way to either:

- Fix that plugin, or
- Hack `post.php` to add a working "AJAX Save" button?

Interestingly, WordPress already has an AJAX update functionality which it uses when Auto-Saving. Perhaps that could be starting point?

I truly believe this is an important UX issue and would greatly appreciate your help. Thank you!

Comment: Very good proposition but it risks to fall under the "[not a real question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq#close)" category. You'd better try to find what's not working in the plugin and search/ask for solutions here. Or make a pure *Ajax Save button* question. I'd also suggest that you joined [wp-hackers list](http://lists.automattic.com/mailman/listinfo/wp-hackers) and shoot the UX issue there.

Answer (score 1):

The german (core) developer [Dominik Schilling/ocean90](http://wpgrafie.de/wp-plugins/preserve-editor-scroll-position/) has released a pretty nice, simple and small plugin to encounter (part of) this problem. Instead of adding a complex AJAX save process, that would just make it harder to work with even handlers and such (de- & re-registering them), he just added a position marker, that allows WP to determine your current position after a save process and scroll back to it.

You can [download the plugin over the official repo](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/preserve-editor-scroll-position/).